# Send data from iPhone using 3G connection

Tags: iphone, sockets, wifi, send, 3g

I have a Java Applicaction in where I have a TCP Server that accepts conections with Sockets. So I have done a Socket in C inside the iPhone app to send a String to my Java app and when I use the WiFi connection everything works perfect.

I type a string in a textfield in the iPhone app, I press send button and I recive that string on my Java app. But when I turn off the WiFi and I try with the 3G connection nothing happens. What I need to do to get that? There is a differente socket or method to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think both should work the same. take a look a this:[BSD Sockets don't behave in a iPhone 3G environment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2488634/bsd-sockets-dont-behave-in-a-iphone-3g-environment)

Maybe you are using the BSD sockets, those don't activate the 3G radio.